# Adding attachment with sendgrid npm not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

I'm using the sendgrid Node.js module to send an email. I have a file already on the server and want to add it as an attachment to the email. I'm finding the email goes through fine but without the attachment so not sure what's going wrong.

```
//sendgrid credentials
var mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(sendGrid({ 
  auth: { 
    api_user: conf.mail.user, 
    api_key: conf.mail.pass
  } 
}));

//mail object
var mailObj = {
  to: toAddr, 
  from: fromAddr, 
  subject: subject, 
  html: template,
  files: [{
    path: __dirname + "/../../uploads/" + filename
  }]
};

//send mail
mailer.sendMail(mailObj, function(err, res){ 
  if (err) throw err; 
});
```

The above is wrapped in a larger function which passes through variables including `filename`. Things to bear in mind:

- The filename gets passed to the function fine
- The file exists in the location specified
- The email currently sends WITHOUT the attachment

Comment: Can you also post your template? Or the relevant part of it?

Comment: @Zlatko The template is just some HTML for the body of the email. That is working fine. The email sends with the subject and body. As soon as I tried adding an attachment is where it all went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the attachment really isn't in the message? If you "show raw" (how you do that depends on your mail client), and look through it, you can see the different MIME parts, and confirm if the attachment truly isn't there, or of it's just a matter of it not being displayed.

If it's there but not seen, this is an issue of MIME order, and may be related to a SendGrid account setting, called "Convert Plaintext to HTML".
Mail Clients read messages from the bottom up, and expect attachments to be at the bottom. If they get to display content before an attachment, they stop with the display content, and never 'see' the attachment.
Depending on how your message is being assembled before you pass it to SendGrid, they may be adding HTML to the end, which then makes the attachment effectively invisible. You can turn off that setting by checking the "don't convert" option under your Account Settings.

If the attachment really isn't there, you can check those same MIME parts, and see if:

- The attachment is there, but is 0kb, meaning that the file isn't being read properly.
- The attachment MIME parse is there, but is only composed of the file path, which means the code is just literally attaching the path string, instead of reading the file.